# Windows registry key AppliesTo does not work with Users directory

Tags: c++, windows, registry, contextmenu, regedit

What I am trying to do is to enable a customized context menu item to appear when users right-click folders in a specific directory.

So in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` I created my key (say with the name: `MyProgram`), and I created the subkey `command` that has the path to my program to run (say, "C:\Users\myuser\myApp\MyProgram.exe").

Until now it is ok and works correctly. But when I add the entry `AppliesTo` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MyProgram` and set it to `C:\Users` it does not work and the context menu item does not appear anymore!

Important Note: My windows language is German and the display name of Users folder in my windows explorer is Benutzer. Whenever I set `AppliesTo` to `C:\Benutzer` instead it works correctly, despite the fact that the `command` works with `Users` path properly! Alsowhen I `echo %USERPROFILE%` in the cmd it is printed in English as `C:\Users\myuser` and not Benutzer.

Is there a way to programmatically get the display path of Users or any folder in the system?

Please note: I cannot simply write Benutzer instead of Users in the path because the path can be dynamic. I am doing it programmatically and want my code to have **consistent behavior in different machines with different languages**. I am using C++ winreg API to set the registry values (for example: RegOpenKeyEx() and RegSetValueEx()).

Below is an export of the working version of the key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MyProgram]
"AppliesTo"="C:\\Benutzer\\myuser"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MyProgram\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\myuser\\path\\to\\MyProgram.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Use ``SHGetKnownFolderPath`` to retrieve those paths: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried it now but it returned the path in English (i.e. C:\Users\myuser).

Comment: Then use it's Unicode API instead. You are probably using it's ANSI version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The localized name of folders can be obtained using the function `SHGetLocalizedName`, however it requires some additional work to get the string representation of the localized name. The following code snippet shows an example of how to do it.

```
PWSTR name = new WCHAR[100];;
PCWSTR folder = TEXT("C:\\Users");
UINT len=100;
int id=0;

HRESULT hr = SHGetLocalizedName(folder, name, len, &id);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", name);
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings(name, name, len);
    HMODULE shell_handle = LoadLibraryEx(name, NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    if (shell_handle) {
        if (LoadString(shell_handle, id, name, len) != 0) {
            wprintf(L"%ls\n", name);
        }
        FreeLibrary(shell_handle);
    }
}
```

The result of the previous code will be Benutzer in case of German locale.

You will need to include the following headers as well

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
```